# Find the center of a circle given the radius and two points on the perimeter

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I think I have enough information to get an answer here, but the solution continues to elude me. I have a circle with radius r whose center is at (x,y). I also have two points outside the circle V0 (a, b) and V1 (a, c) that are a fixed distance away from the two points, K, and aligned vertically with one another. Note that I do not know the value of K, only that K is a fixed value.

[image: Overview]

Great. So, calculating the y component of the center is simple -

y = c - b

But I'm at a loss as to how to calculate the x component of the center! I can see how one could calculate angle a using some simple trig, but I'm not sure how I would use that to get to my goal which is to know the center of the circle. Can this be done without knowing K? It FEELS like this should be possible, but perhaps not.

Looking forward to seeing what people think!

Thanks,
Marshall

Comment: You need to be more explicit in your assumptions. The picture suggests that the two known points $V_0$ and $V_1$ are *horizontally* aligned with their corresponding points on the circle, and that they are *vertically* aligned with respect to each other, but the text does not say so. It'll help if you make these assumption explicit. It'll also help to draw the (vertical) lines connecting the points $V_0$ and $V_1$ and the two points on the circle, along with the (horizontal) line from the center of the circle out to the midpoint of the line connecting $V_0$ and $V_1$....

Comment: ...  Finally, it'll help to make the components of $V_0$ and $V_1$ explicit, say $V_0=(a,b)$ and $V_1=(a,c)$ (the repetition of $a$ agreeing with the points' vertical alignment). That will facilitate finding the correct formula for the $y$ component of the center of the circle; the formula $y=V_1-V_0$ is not correct. (Technically it's not even meaningful, since $V_0$ and $V_1$ are *points*, while $y$ is a *number*.)

Comment: I believe I've made the assumptions a bit more explicit - indeed V0 and V1 are horizontally aligned with the corresponding points on the circle and are vertically aligned with respect to each other. I added the vertical line between V0 and V1 as well as the chord on the circle, but did not add the midpoint line from the center of the circle to the center of V0V1 - I felt like that made the diagram a bit too busy. Looking forward to your thoughts and any additional advice you might have for clarification!

Comment: The image has disappeared altogether!

Comment: Brilliant! Sorry about that - image replaced...

Comment: I cannot see that that there is a unique solution. $y$ may be fixed, but $x$ can be anything.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the $x$-coordinate of $V_0$ and $V_1$ is known. Denote it $x_V.$

The $x$-coordinate of the center is $x=x_V+h,$ where $h$ is the height of the isosceles triangle with sides $r,r,y_1-y_0.$